# Moving images with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple batch file that will move all images from a folder and all its sub-folders over to another single folder. I am inexperienced and after piecing together a collection of results from Google I came up with the following code which I thought would work:

```
@echo off
set /p srcfolder="Enter the source folder: "
set /p trgfolder="Enter the target folder: "
for /r %srcfolder% %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" %trgfolder%
echo Process complete
pause&exit
```

Is anyone able to help me with where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential problem was that in a batch file the `for metavariables` use two `%%` percent characters.

I added quotes to enable long filenames and so the input names should not have quotes, and changed the `copy` to a `move` command.

```
@echo off
set /p srcfolder="Enter the source folder: "
set /p trgfolder="Enter the target folder: "
for /r "%srcfolder%" %%f in (*.jpg) do move "%%f" "%trgfolder%"
echo Process complete
pause&exit
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

So forgive me for being ignorant here, but if I was using...

`for /r %srcfolder% %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" %trgfolder%`

... directly in the command line it would work? But for use with a batch file I'd need to ensure there are two percentage signs on each?

Comment: `for /r "c:\source" %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" "d:\target"` <-- something like that should work.